PyCharm - переход к определению
Переход к определению (jump to definition) - обычно работает как комбинация левого клика мыши + Ctrl.
Пробовал разные комбинации (Shift вместо Ctrl, либо одновременно, и разное другое), читал StOv, документацию, искал в File/Settings - не понимаю. Как это здесь работает?

Для перехода к определению используйте комбинацию клавишей Ctrl+B.


cannot find declaration to go to

Значит, работает! Только вы применили эту команду в неправильном месте. Сначала кликните на место в программе, где какое-то предыдущее определение используете.
